# Challenge for polygon display within leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

We have a specific design challenge for polygon display within leaflet (latest version).

We have polygons which are rendered with a solid border as well as a semi-transparent background.
We are looking for a way to draw a solid borderline as well as a wider "inline" border and no background.

> Note: the question is for polygons not rectangular. The below image
> and code is just for example.

Is there any way to achieve this?

```
var polygon = L.polygon([
  [ 51.72872938200587, -2.415618896484375 ],
  [ 51.72872938200587, -2.080535888671875 ],
  [ 51.901918172561714, -2.080535888671875 ],
  [ 51.901918172561714, -2.415618896484375 ],
  [ 51.72872938200587, -2.415618896484375 ]

],{
 color:'#2F538F',
 fillOpacity: 0.9,
 fillColor: '#BFBFBF',
}).addTo(map);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable by utilizing **leaftlet**'s class [extension](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html) system.

To start with, leaflet's [class diagram](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/class-diagram.html) could be consulted to determine where the extension is needed. As a general rule, first try to extend classes towards the root, and prefer *L.Class.extend* over *L.Class.include*.

**Working Solution:**

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-polygon-multiple-borders-4dix0?file=/CanvasWithExtraStyles.js)

One approach is hooking into the rendering process. In the following example, L.Canvas is extended to a custom L.Canvas.WithExtraStyles class (leaflet's plugin building [guidelines](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html)). The custom [Renderer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#renderer) is then provided to map.

In this approach, note that multiple borders and fills (both inset and outset) could be provided using the `extraStyles` config.

`extraStyle` custom property accepts **Array of** [PathOptions](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#path). With an additional `inset`, whose value could be positive or a negative number of pixels representing the **offset** form the border of the main geometry. A negative value of `inset` will put the border outside of the original polygon.

*While implementing such customizations, special care must be taken to make sure leaflet is not considering the added customizations as separate geometric shapes. Otherwise interactive functionalities e.g. Polygon Edit or Leaflet Draw will have unexpected behaviour*.

```js
// CanvasWithExtraStyles.js
// First step is to provide a special renderer which accept configuration for extra borders.
// Here L.Canvas is extended using Leaflet's class system
const styleProperties = ['stroke', 'color', 'weight', 'opacity', 'fill', 'fillColor', 'fillOpacity'];

/*
 * @class Polygon.MultiStyle
 * @aka L.Polygon.MultiStyle
 * @inherits L.Polygon
 */
L.Canvas.WithExtraStyles = L.Canvas.extend({
  _updatePoly: function(layer, closed) {
    const centerCoord = layer.getCenter();
    const center = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(centerCoord);
    const originalParts = layer._parts.slice();

    // Draw extra styles
    if (Array.isArray(layer.options.extraStyles)) {
      const originalStyleProperties = styleProperties.reduce(
        (acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: layer.options[cur] }),
        {}
      );
      const cx = center.x;
      const cy = center.y;

      for (let eS of layer.options.extraStyles) {
        const i = eS.inset || 0;

        // For now, the algo doesn't support MultiPolygon
        // To have it support MultiPolygon, find centroid
        // of each MultiPolygon and perform the following
        layer._parts[0] = layer._parts[0].map(p => {
          return {
            x: p.x < cx ? p.x + i : p.x - i,
            y: p.y < cy ? p.y + i : p.y - i
          };
        });

        //Object.keys(eS).map(k => layer.options[k] = eS[k]);
        Object.keys(eS).map(k => (layer.options[k] = eS[k]));
        L.Canvas.prototype._updatePoly.call(this, layer, closed);
      }

      // Resetting original conf
      layer._parts = originalParts;
      Object.assign(layer.options, originalStyleProperties);
    }

    L.Canvas.prototype._updatePoly.call(this, layer, closed);
  }
});
// Leaflet's conventions to also provide factory methods for classes
L.Canvas.withExtraStyles = function(options) {
  return new L.Canvas.WithExtraStyles(options);
};


// --------------------------------------------------------------

// map.js
const map = L.map("map", {
  center: [52.5145206, 13.3499977],
  zoom: 18,
  renderer: new L.Canvas.WithExtraStyles()
});

new L.tileLayer(
  "https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  {
    attribution: `attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>`,
    detectRetina: true
  }
).addTo(map);

// Map center
const { x, y } = map.getSize();

// Left Polygon
const polyStyle1 = {
  color: '#2f528f',
  extraStyles: [
    {
      color: 'transparent',
      weight: 10,
      fillColor: '#d9d9d9'
    }
  ]
};

// Sudo coordinates are generated form map container pixels
const polygonCoords1 = [
  [0, 10],
  [300, 10],
  [300, 310],
  [0, 310]
].map(point => map.containerPointToLatLng(point));
const polygon1 = new L.Polygon(polygonCoords1, polyStyle1);
polygon1.addTo(map);

// Right Polygon
const polyStyle2 = {
  fillColor: "transparent",
  color: '#2f528f',
  extraStyles: [
    {
      inset: 6,
      color: '#d9d9d9',
      weight: 10
    }
  ]
};

const polygonCoords2 = [
  [340, 10],
  [640, 10],
  [640, 310],
  [340, 310]
].map(point => map.containerPointToLatLng(point));
const polygon2 = new L.Polygon(polygonCoords2, polyStyle2);
polygon2.addTo(map);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="map" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vw">0012</div>
```

**Ideal Solution:**

- Implement a plugin as a separate npm module.
- Try to extend or hook into [Renderer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#renderer) itself instead of separately extending L.Canvas and L.SVG.
- Hook the cusomization into base class [Path](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#path) instead of individual shapes: Polygon, Polyline or Circle.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Recatngle/Polygon method.

> ```
> // define rectangle geographical bounds
> var bounds = [[54.559322, -5.767822], [56.1210604, -3.021240]];
> // create an orange rectangle
> L.rectangle(bounds, {}).addTo(map);
> ```

The Use options to get the desired effect on the lines. Options are inherited from [polyline options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polyline-option)

There you can tweak `color`, `opacity`, `fill`, `fillColor`, `fillOpacity` and `fillRule` to get the desired effect on the lines

Comment: thanks, But It is a polygon, not a rectangle, the image and code in question is just for example.

Comment: You can use the same polyline options for polygons too. They all inherit from the same base calss.

Comment: yes, we can use the options but what if the shape is not the exact Rectangle. it can be a hexagonal shape

Comment: You can get any shape using Polygon. And use options to shape the lines the way you want.